# Getting radio button selected before running function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with radio buttons and some td's and when I click on a row the radio button in that row gets checked.

```
$("#usernames_table").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
if (!$(e.target).is('input:radio')) {
    $(this).find("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
            }
        });
```

Now every time a radio button gets checked I run an AJAX call and it works **if** I click directly on the radio button  but not if I click on the row which trigger the function to make the radio button checked.

```
jQuery('#myform').on('change', 'input[name=information]:radio', function (e) {
```

Here is some code of my table

```
trHTML += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="information" value="' + usernames[i] + '"></td></tr>'
```

I have no idea why it is not getting triggered: the table is inside #myform and then inside #usernames_table.

Comment: where and when is your ajax happening? I see that you bind a `change` event but you `trigger` `click`

Comment: The ajax request is inside -> jQuery('#myform').on('change'){ ajax here! } which  gets triggered by -> $("#usernames_table").on('click')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fire change event after setting the checked property as your handler is listening to change event handler. Also changing the checked property programatically won't trigger change event.

```
$(this).find("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about that. Your solution works perfectly.